AutoHotKey Script closes instantly and can't figure out if it would even work
This is a script to automatically farm in a game.
I am currently upgrading it to AHK v2 and added that the keys would be sent to that specific window.
Problems:

The script closes instantly when I start it.
Because it closes idk if it would work the way i used the id of the window because i used another script from a friend that was written in v1 and had ahk_id %id% for id but that gave me an error that global ahk_id was not set so i changed it.

#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

SetTitleMatchMode 2
#SingleInstance Force

id := 0

{
    MouseGetPos , , &id, &control
    return
}

Hotkey  "!^w",  "sWin"
Hotkey  "f24",  "rel"
Hotkey  "f20",  "wgar"
Hotkey  "f21",  "fsug"
Hotkey  "f22",  "fpum"
Hotkey  "f13",  "wda"
Hotkey  "f14",  "wcas"
Hotkey  "f15",  "whub"
Hotkey  "f23",  "fcho"

SelectWindow:
{
    MouseGetPos , , &id, &control
    return
}


rel:
{
    ControlClick , id, , "Left", , "NAU"
    ControlClick , id, , "Middle", , "NAU"
    ControlSend "{a up}{s up}{d up}{w up}", , id 
    reload
    return
}

fsug:
{
    ControlSend "t", , id
    sleep 100
    ControlSend "{NumpadDiv}warp garden{Enter}1", , id
    sleep 100
    ControlClick , id, , "Left", , "NAD"
    loop 15
        {
            ControlSend "{a down}", , id
            sleep 47750
            ControlSend "{a up}{s down}", , id 
            sleep 47750
            ControlSend "{s up}", , id 
        }
    ControlSend "{d down}", , id
    sleep 9500
    ControlClick , id, , "Left", , "NAU"
    ControlSend "{d up}", , id 
    return
}

wgar:
{
    ControlSend "t", , id
    sleep 100
    ControlSend "{NumpadDiv}warp garden{Enter}1", , id
    return
}

fpum:
{
    ControlSend "t", , id
    sleep 100
    ControlSend "{NumpadDiv}warp garden{Enter}1", , id
    sleep 100
    loop 2
        {
            ControlClick , id, , "Left", , "NAD"
            ControlSend "{w down}", , id
            loop 6
                {
                    ControlSend "{a down}", , id
                    sleep 72500
                    ControlSend "{a up}{d down}", , id
                    sleep 72500
                    ControlSend "{d up}", , id
                }
            ControlClick , id, , "Left", , "NAU"
            ControlSend "{w up}t", , id
            sleep 100
            ControlSend "{NumpadDiv}warp garden{Enter}1", , id
            sleep 100
        }
    return
}

wda:
{
    ControlSend "t", , id
    sleep 100
    ControlSend "{NumpadDiv}warp da{Enter}", , id
    return
}

wcas:
{
    ControlSend "t", , id
    sleep 100
    ControlSend "{NumpadDiv}warp castle{Enter}", , id
    return
}

whub:
{
    ControlSend "t", , id
    sleep 100
    ControlSend "{NumpadDiv}warp hub{Enter}", , id
    return
}

fcho:
{
    loop
        {
            ControlClick , id, , "Middle", , "NAD"
            sleep 3
            ControlClick , id, , "Middle", , "NAU"
            sleep 3
        }
}

I am expecting it to stay active.
things used for id : ahk_id %id% ; %id% ; id

Syntax is incorrect.
Your functions should look like this:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

Hotkey "!1", test

test(k){
    MsgBox("Hello")
}


Please read:

about hotkeys: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm
about the Hotkey function: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Hotkey.htm

